# In GCP Dataflow, what does "Part Running" mean?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

When you submit an Apache Beam program to Google Cloud Platform's Dataflow product, you can see a graph of the various stages of your pipeline, whether they are running and how quickly, etc (see screenshot at bottom).

Sometimes a stage will have the status `Part Running`. Sometimes it can even have that status before the previous stage is `Running`. What does `Part Running` mean?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expend the step (with the arrow in the upper right) you could see all the steps that compose this macro step. Some are running, other are waiting.

By the way, the summary of the macro step is "partial running".

Answer (score -1):

Part Running means "Partial Running", when using transforms that contains multiple nested sub-transforms, it is called [composite transforms](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-monitoring-intf#composite-transforms).

If you open the step you could see other transformations running or waiting, when both states occur, you are getting "Part running"